# spring data mongo transition

Tags: mongodb, transition

No collection was created in Mongo（No user collection）, Using template to save objects(save user object)

```
   @Transactional
   public void saveSingleObject() {
        template.save(new User("james", "james", 'ddd'));
   }

exception : Command failed with error 263 (OperationNotSupportedInTransaction): 'Cannot create namespace test-mongo.processes in multi-document transaction.

but User collection in mongo , no exception
```

Answer (score 2):

This is happening since as per Mongo documentation "a multi-document transaction cannot include an insert operation that would result in the creation of a new collection." For more please refer [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/).